# Partial derivatives of functions with a change in variable

Tags: calculus

Say if I have a function $x = x(u,v)$, and then two further functions $u= u(s,t)$ and $v = v(s,t)$, I was wondering how I would go about taking a partial derivative with respect to s.

Comment: Do you really mean a partial of something wrt $x$, or do you mean a partial of $x$ wrt (say) $s$?

Comment: @MPW I did indeed mean wrt s

Answer (score 1):

The rule is

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}$$

You would add more terms of the same form if there were more variables like your $u$ and $v$. So you could write that if $x=x(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n)$, and each of the $u_i$ were functions $u_i = u_i(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m)$, then for each $j = 1,2,\ldots,m$,

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s_j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u_i}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial s_j}$$

Note that in this sum, $j$ is fixed (since your are looking for $\partial x/\partial s_j$) and the sum has one term for each of the $u_i$.

The $u_i$ are the "input slots" for $x$, each of which in turn depend on all of the $s_j$.

Answer (score 0):

A tree diagram is probably helpful here:

[image]

This shows which variables are functions of which other variables. From the diagram, you can use the chain rule to come up with

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}$$